# Cursor does not blink on autofocus

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, security

Browser: Chrome > 57

Issue:

Cursor does NOT blink on the focus'd text box ( Left/Right click nothing will make the cursor start blinking )

Steps:

Happens when you proceed from **"Your connection is not private"**, aka- unsafe page.

Only happens when you get the warning page ( A self-signed-cert page ) and you proceed by clicking on **proceed to < ip/domain > ( unsafe )**  - the issue does not happen the next time you refresh ( as the warning page does not come anymore )

What I have tried, 
Tried

- html way, autofocus="autofocus" on the input-textbox
- javascript way, $(id).focus(). Tried setting the focus after some timeout as well.

None of the above methods work ( 1st time i'm accessing the page - after warning page ). **Focus is actually set/working**, just the blinking isn't working.

FYI: Chrome updated some security changes from version 58 and onwards ( details [1](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/security-changes-in-chrome-58/), [2](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/854) ). Not sure if/why these changes would be affecting the way cursor blinks, but I have checked in Chrome 56/57 and the blinking is working.

Ex, do not want to link any unsafe websites to demo this. The problem I'm facing is for a private software installation - self signed cert ( required ), and the cursor blinking ( on the focused element ) is not working.

Comment: Might want to deal with the security issue first, if you're the site administrator. Obviously as you pointed out, once you deal with that, the other issue won't occur. In addition you might find that no one will visit your site and even notice that bug if the first thing they're presented with is a bright red warning screen telling them they shouldn't visit.

Comment: The site is on a private network ( secure ). It's not accessible to the outside.

Comment: In that case is there any reason the site needs to run over HTTPS? If not, switch to HTTP and don't use self-signed certificates. Problem solved.

Comment: I'm not site admin, that's not in my control. Need to find a solution to enable the blinking feature back. The focus actually is set, when i'm typing - text does come up. Just blinking doesnt seem to be happening.

Comment: I also have the same problem. Only happens if you're coming from "Your connection is not private" page, cursor does not blink but input works. I suspect `onFocus` and `onBlur` handlers don't work either. This doesn't happen the next time, and is fixed if you change tabs.

Comment: Raised an issue on chromium - [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=753754)

Comment: issue seems to be fixed. Guessing it was a problem seen between chrome version 59 --  60

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color

It's probably because of new update.

An Example: http://www.developphp.com/lib/CSS/caret-color

Comment: the problem isnt with the focus not working. The problem is with blinking not happening even if the textbox is focused.

Comment: @VivekChandra can you check the link that i gave it seems like caret-color property for css integrated with chrome 57 release. 
`caret-color: #000;`

Comment: @berkaykılıç awesome, your answer helped me

Comment: This thing helped me but only few input fieds had issues all others were wroking fine, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - a text field within a foreign object as part of a SVG offering. The solution for me was to set (force) the cursor to auto just before giving the input field focus.

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
$(id).focus();
```